# Filter aggregation keys with non nested mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have following mapping:

```
{
  "Country": {
    "properties": {
      "State": {
        "properties": {
          "Name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "Code": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "Lang": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is sample document:

```
{
  "Country": {
    "State": [
      {
        "Name": "California",
        "Code": "CA",
        "Lang": "EN"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Alaska",
        "Code": "AK",
        "Lang": "EN"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Texas",
        "Code": "TX",
        "Lang": "EN"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am querying on this index to get aggregates of count of states by name. I am using following query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Country.State.Name: *Ala*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Country.State.Name.raw",
        "include": ".*Ala.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to get only keys matching with query_string using `include` regex in terms aggregation but seems there is no way to make it case insensitive regex in `include`.

The result I want is:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "counts": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Alaska",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there other solution available to get me only keys matching query_string without using nested mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using inline script to filter the keys. (Still a dirty fix but it solves my use case for now and I can avoid mapping changes)

Here is how I am executing query.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Country.State.Name: *Ala*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['Country.State.Name.raw'].value.toLowerCase().contains('ala') ? doc['Country.State.Name.raw'].value : null",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) for keyword datatype. Below is the sample mapping:

### Mapping:

```
PUT country
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {                              <---- Note this
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Country": {
        "properties": {
          "State": {
            "properties": {
              "Name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "my_normalizer"      <---- Note this
                  }
                }
              },
              "Code": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                  }
                }
              },
              "Lang": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Document:

```
POST country/_doc/1
{
  "Country": {
    "State": [
      {
        "Name": "California",
        "Code": "CA",
        "Lang": "EN"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Alaska",
        "Code": "AK",
        "Lang": "EN"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Texas",
        "Code": "TX",
        "Lang": "EN"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST country/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Country.State.Name: *Ala*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Country.State.Name.raw",
        "include": "ala.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the query pattern in `include`. Basically all the values of the `*.raw` fields that you have, would be stored in `lowercase letters` due to the normalizer that I've applied.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "counts" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "alaska",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Liked your solution but fixing the mapping was my last option. Also I don't want to modify data (key) of aggregation. I wanted Alaska but with your solution it gives alaska. BTW Thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: @Kapil If you want case insensitive search for `keyword` type, that is the only option I believe you have. Anyways, good luck and you are always welcome!!